# Proving that the intersection over a general index is the null set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intersection-theory

Prove that the generalized intersection of the interval $[n,n+2]$ is the empty set.
 I can prove this by contradiction by assuming that there there is an $x$ in the intersection such that $n+2<x.$ I am just not sure where to go from there.

Comment: What is the indexing set here exactly? $\mathbb N, \mathbb Z, \mathbb Q$?

Comment: I accidentally left out that the indexing set is Z

Comment: In that case, note that you have two set in your collection $[-3, -1]$ and $[1, 3]$ and their intersection is empty set. So the intersection of the whole collection is empty set. (You can choose different sets also. It doesn't matter as long as they are disjoint.)

Comment: Okay, thank you, that makes sense. I am trying to prove by contradiction, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X:=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb Z}[n,n+2]$ is non-empty and let $x\in X.$ Then we have $n \leq x \leq n+2, \forall n \in \mathbb Z.$ In particular, $-3 \leq x \leq -1$ and $1 \leq x \leq 3.$ This gives a contradiction.